# Can't install printer, cups problem?

Tags: printing

I'm new to Ubuntu, using Ubuntu 16.04.

In **System Settings > Hardware > Printers** it says

> Printing service not available. Start the service on this computer or connect to another server.

The start service button is locked. When I press <kbd>connect</kbd> it opens  a window where I only have one option: **CUPS server: localhost**

When I try to connect I get a dialog:

> CUPS server error
>   there was an error during the CUPS operation:'failed to connect to server'.

Edit1:

the printer is samsung scx ,via network.
the printer is working, i can even print from the windows dualboot in the same laptop.

Edit 2:

sudo service cups restart- no output.
localhost:631- not working

Edit 3:

> dpkg -l cups

output

```
ohad@ohad-X556UAK:~$ dpkg -l cups
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-
aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-
=================================
un  cups           <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please help us help you by [edit]ing  your post to provide further detail. What printer are you trying to connect to? How is it connected? Networked? USB? LPT?  For further tips on how to get the best results, please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the printer is samsung scx ,via network.
the printer is working,
i can even print from the windows dualboot in the same laptop

Comment: In your browser go to `localhost:631`. What do you see?
If you do not see the `cups` page, try restarting `cups` using `sudo service cups restart`.

Comment: sudo service cups restart- no output.
localhost:631- not working

Comment: Please [edit] in the output of `dpkg -l cups`

Comment: I went here and installed a new CUPS ... worked like a charm https://linuxhint.com/cups_print_server_ubuntu/

Answer (score 15):

I had exactly the same problem and this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install cups --reinstall
sudo service cups restart
```

Answer (score 6):

I met similar situation today and found this solution to be useful:

```
sudo apt-get install smbclient
```

[refer_link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908495)

Comment: worked for me on 19.10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Canon MG8250 on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04

Using the cups web-interface enabled me to add the printer.

1. open a browser and got to http://localhost:631/ . You will get a website Home - CUPS x.x.x
2. Select "Adding Printers and Classes"
3. Button "Add Printer"

At one point you will be asked for your user and password.

Comment: "Add Printer" is under the "Administration" tab but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

so for some reason, you don't have cups installed; if you open your software centre, and type in cups; and right-click to select INSTALL, it should install cups and the associated programmes it needs; then try to add a printer after doing that

Comment: was loking for "CUPS" and it find "printers". I removed it and reinstall. but the problem remaining...